# Getting error when trying to Build container image function for AWS Lambda

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, imagemagick

I am new to Docker. I am trying to deploy a function that crops image and adds a frame to it. As I need to crop HEIC files too I use and MagickWand/ImageMagic and I cannot deploy them as a layer that's why I need to deploy as an image.

Now here is the Dockerfile.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

COPY app/app.py /app/

COPY requirements.txt  .
RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target /app/
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get install libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends -y

CMD [ "image_converter.lambda_handler" ]
```

this command is suppesed to install MagickWand/ImageMagic

```
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get install libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends -y
```

When I run `docker build myimage -t gag .` i get the following error message

```
The command '/bin/sh -c DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get install libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends -y' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

It was working before when I had `FROM ubuntu:latest` instead of `FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8`

This is what project directory looks like
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

I'm adding docker logs

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  15.87kB
Step 1/6 : FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8
 ---> 1e9250a95dc6
Step 2/6 : COPY app/app.py /app/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a300efeb608c
Step 3/6 : COPY requirements.txt  .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c2bfef8f1017
Step 4/6 : RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target /app/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4bdd4a1c4438
Step 5/6 : RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends -y
 ---> Running in fb6132656626
/bin/sh: sudo: command not found
The command '/bin/sh -c DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends -y' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Comment: That's not a deploy time error, it's a build time error. If you look up the Linux `127` status code it indicates you need to add `sudo` to the command you are trying to run. I suspect there is a more detailed error message in the docker build log that is stating this as well. This is most likely due to the fact that the default user for `public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8` is not `root.

Comment: I tried with sudo but it said command not found and than returned the same error
Honestly I just tried to implement what was the python 3.8 part in this document and I'm kinda stuck with this issue.

Comment: How about showing more of the docker build log, instead of just the final status code?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Amazon is going to be building docker images based on Amazon Linux, not Ubuntu/Debian. So you would need to use `yum` to install packages, not `apt`.

Comment: I'v updated the question and included docker build log.

Answer (score 1):

I use that image and is a CentOS image. Try to use yum instead of apt. Try something like this:

yum install -y ImageMagick-devel

Comment: Finally the answer I was looking for :)