# How to install imagemagick as lambda layer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, imagemagick

I need to use ImageMagick in my lambda fanction as a layer.
I used [this](https://github.com/upload-io/aws-image-magick-example) repository and followed [this](https://upload.io/blog/installing-imagemagick-on-amazon-linux-2/) tutorial. I ended up having these files
[image], zipped them into python.zip file and they follow this structure python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/"actual files". I uploaded the zip file in AWS Lambda, tested the code and got the following error.

```
START RequestId: 3c4a1a77-b698-408d-ae18-5f31709628b4 Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': MagickWand shared library not found.
You probably had not installed ImageMagick library.
Try to install:
  https://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/guide/install.html
Traceback (most recent call last):END RequestId: 3c4a1a77-b698-408d-ae18-5f31709628b4
REPORT RequestId: 3c4a1a77-b698-408d-ae18-5f31709628b4  Duration: 1.83 ms   Billed Duration: 2 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 50 MB  Init Duration: 323.60 ms
```

I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Follow the steps outlined here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64462403/3390419

Comment: That was helpful, but the problem is that I can't install ImageMagick with pip, it's installed with apt so     $ pip install --target . -r requirements.txt won't work for me.

Comment: Use container lambda images for that.

Comment: Well I've tried but I'm having some trouble finding a way to install imageMagick to a container. the issue is detailed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72687068/getting-error-when-trying-to-build-container-image-function-for-aws-lambda